# How can I connect to wlp2s network

Tags: wireless-networking, sftp

I switched to Rogers and the network is no longer wlan, but shows wlp2s. I used to see an ip address like 192.168.2.xx when I run

```
ifconfig -a
```

but now there is no such thing any more and the wifi device became wlp2s0, it used to be wlan0. I tried googling and cannot find anything. pasting the output with some address deletion as I do not know if it is safe to post all I see:

```
wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.xx  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 2607:fea8:58e1:1cb0:b4b0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::9d6b:43ec:aacc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2607:fea8:58e1:1cb0  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2607:fea8:58e1:1cb0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether f4:b7:e2:00:ea:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

I would like to connect from filezilla on another box on my home network and need the ip address.

Comment: the IP address is `10.0.0.xx` - note, addresses like `192.168.x.x` and `10.x.x.x` are "private" so no need to hide them as they won't be accessible outside your LAN

Comment: brilliant. post that as an answer and I will acknowledge it. I thought the lan was always 192.168

Comment: What's your overall network look like? - Its odd that your network naming convention changed, I see 'valid' IPv6 addresses and a plausible ipv4 'lan' scoped address

Comment: The name is due to "predictable net names". Your ISP didn't cause this.

Comment: See [this](/questions/158291/whats-the-meaning-of-10-0-0-1-24-address-of-my-computer-from-the-ip-addr-com/158298#158298) answer or [this](/questions/917903/what-is-the-ipv6-equivalent-of-192-168-xxx-xxx/917912#917912) for more info and links about private networks and [this](/questions/1292653/what-is-the-meaning-of-entries-when-running-ifconfig-a/1292993#1292993) one about "*Predictable Network Interface Names*" whose introduction caused the [change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702161/why-is-my-interface-now-wlp2s0-instead-of-wlan0) from wlan0 to wlp2s0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So called "Private" (or non-routable) IP addresses come in three "ranges"

- The familiar 192.168.x.x
- The less familiar 10.x.x.x
- And the rare 172.16-31.x.x

So, in your case, the IP address is the `10.0.0.xx`

Comment: FWIW, "less familiar" and "rare" are relative terms. Maybe they're not used in home/SOHO environments much, but they're used quite regularly in enterprise networking. Also, for the benefit of future readers: the standard that defines these "private" IPv4 ranges is [RFC 1918](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt).